# Skip attributes having nil values when to_json on ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, json, activerecord

I was wondering if there is any way to just skip attributes having nil
values when to_json on ActiveRecord.
The default behavior is to include a nil value.

Is there an option way to make this value just not appear?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@lars's answer will work for a single object, but for an array of Active Record objects, you will have to iterate through every element of the array and do the conversion. If you want this conversion everytime you call `.to_json` or `render :json =>` for that model, you can override the `as_json` function in the model like this:

```
class Model
  ..
  def as_json(options={})
    super(options).reject { |k, v| v.nil? }
  end
end
```

Also, I am assuming you have defined, `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false` in the your environment(`config/initializers/active_record.rb` in Rails 3 and `config/initializers/new_rails_defaults.rb` in Rails 2). Otherwise, you will have to implement @lars's function fully in the model(taking `value[0]` to get the attribute hash etc.).

**Use this method only if you want to do this everytime you call `.to_json` or `render :json =>` for that model**. Otherwise you should stick to @lars's answer.

Comment: that wont work. that will be equal to `.reject { |a| a.nil? }` where `a` will be array like this `[k, v]`

Answer (score 4):

You can get at the Hash representation of an ActiveRecord object used for serializing to JSON through the `as_json` method.

The hash will have the (underscored) class name as the only key, and the value will be another hash containing the attributes of the class.

```
hash = object.as_json # Convert to hash
hash.values[0].reject! {|k,v| v.nil?} # Remove attributes with value nil
hash.to_json # Convert to JSON string
```

Answer (score 0):

For any hash array, here is what I usually do considering that any value besides false and nil will be considered true:

```
filtered_array = array.select{|k,v| v}
```

Or the bang alternative:

```
array.select!{|k,v| v}
```

This will NOT work, though, if the values could reliably be the boolean value false.