# ActiveRecord to_json to exclude null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord

Is there an ActiveRecord setting that will allow me to remove null values before serializing ActiveRecord objects into json?

If not, what's the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914022/skip-attributes-having-nil-values-when-to-json-on-activerecord

Comment: `Tag.select("word, followers_count, posts_count").as_json.each{|h| h.reject!{|k,v| v.nil? } }.to_json`

Answer (score 4):

You can override `serializable_hash` method inside your model

```
def serializable_hash(options)
  super(options).select { |_, v| v }
end
```

By the way, if you are going to use include (e.g. `Project.all.as_json(include: :tasks)`) then you need to override `serializable_hash` in both models.

#### UPDATE: Version 0.10+

```
def serializable_hash(adapter_options = nil, options = {}, adapter_instance = self.class.serialization_adapter_instance)
  super(adapter_options, options, adapter_instance).select { |_, v| v }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
@instance.attributes.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }.to_json
```