# Render JSON: Remove null fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I need to avoid having null fields when rendering a JSON from a `Ruby-on-Rails` API:

```
def index
  @items = Item.all
  render json: @items,
end
```

If my Item objects contain nil fields, they are serialized as null in the JSON. I'd just like to eliminate the null fields from my JSON.

Is there any option to `render` for this purpose?

EDIT: Sample output

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "code": "code",
    "list_id": 1,
    "created_by": "me",
    "comment": null
}]
```

EDIT: Duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811628/rails-3-2-replace-null-values-with-empty-string-from-json-serialization)?

The post mentionned has an answer that is not really generic. I'd like to find a solution that would be appliable anywhere with a simple parameter on the `render` (let's say some `skip_nil_values` parameter, for example). The answer to this post nor doesn't mention how to do it, neither how to handle systematically nested objects in the returned JSON.

I'd like to avoid having bloated `as_json` everywhere in my API, each time redefined manually for each new endpoint.

As a last argument, the mentionned post is refering to `Rails 3.2`. I'm in `Rails 5.2`. There may be some improvements between these two versions.

Comment: May you give me a sample output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 3.2: Replace null values with empty string from json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811628/rails-3-2-replace-null-values-with-empty-string-from-json-serialization)

Comment: This could make for a confusing API. Now the consumer must check to see if there is a comment attribute since it will be transient. Is there a reason that null or empty string would be inappropriate?

Comment: The reason is I have a unique consumer that is a `Kotlin` Android app. The responsible developer of this app told me he couldn't handle null values in this language. Furthermore, why sending null values that will increase the payload? The JSON would be lighter without null values. [This is my source](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/285015/251844).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [compact](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/compact) method in Rails that returns a hash with non nil values.
You may use:
`@items.map(&:compact)`

Comment: Is there no more generic way of doing? I'd like avoiding doing it for each new endpoint I'll have. Furthermore, it will be complicated with nested objects.

Comment: Please have a look at this link, this might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914022/skip-attributes-having-nil-values-when-to-json-on-activerecord

Answer (score 0):

Create the following private method in your application controller (name it whatever you want).

```
def format_collection obj_col
  obj_col.as_json.each do |obj|
    obj.reject! { |key, value| value.nil? }
  end
end
```

Replace your render line with the following.

```
render json: format_collection @items
```